# Easygui isn't installing

Tags: python, module, easygui

I want to install easygui on my computer, but it wont work. I have downloaded it, extracted it, and install it just like the tutorials said to do, but every time I  try to run a simle program it just gives me this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\João Teixeira\Documents\lol.py", line 3, in <module>
    import easygui as g
  File "C:\Users\João Teixeira\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\backend.py", line 305, in _custom_import
    module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easygui'
```

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your Python, which you want to download meets requirements of `Easygui`, then when installing select `Add to path` option. After installing:

If Windows:

1. Open CMD
2. Type `pip install easygui` or `python -m pip install easygui`

If Linux:

I can't tell how to install on Unix, but you can see it in docs!